# How do I transfer music to my iPhone?

Tags: iphone

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and I have a first generation iphone,16Gb. The iphone is jailbroken.

Under 10.04, I was able to transfer music onto the phone. I used banshee.
Under 12.04, ubuntu can see the iphone and it's file system. But can't transfer music.

If I just plug the iphone in, rhythymbox can't see the iphone. Banshee can see it *sometimes*, but can't see it's music, and can't transfer music onto it. Attempts to copy over tracks fail with the error "mp3 format is not supported by the device and no converter was found to convert it"

If I plug in the iphone and start nautilus, nautilus can see the iphone, and gives me options for opening it: rhythymbox or a photo management application.

If I then open the phone in rhythymbox, I can see the music collection. But when I attempt to copy files over, the syncing process seems to take forever. The only way to end it is to cancel the sync. Afterwards, no new tracks have been added.

So, how do I transfer file over to my iphone from ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 5):

So far the only way I have been able to put music in my iPhone is by installing an app called `MEWSEEK`. On installed, connect the iPhone to the PC, copy all the songs to the folder `DOWNLOADS` (just the mp3 files and NOT carpets) then unplug the iPhone and run the `MEWSEEK` app, go to the downloads section (all the songs you copied must be there) and at the top right corner tap the sync option. Once done, it will sync the songs.

*Note: the iPhone must be jailbroken, otherwise this wont work.*

Comment: `MEWSEEK` is not available in the appstore!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If your iPhone is running on iOS 5, you cannot accomplish this as of yet with Ubuntu.
"14.10.2011: iOS 5 music sync has a lot of changes. Linux users who want to sponsor the required implementations feel free to donate." (libimobiledevice.org)

Comment: It's an older iphone. 1st gen, incapable of running iOS5. settings->general->about says 3.0.

Comment: Then you would be fine transferring music from and to the iPhone using Rhythmbox. Just drag tracks onto the iPhone.

Comment: Drag it where? No file browser can see the iphone. Neither can rhythymbox.

Answer (score 1):

I had real issues with moving music to my iPhone which is running iOS6.  I tried GTKPOD, followed all sorts of threads and tried in both Ubuntu & Lubuntu but the answer turned out to be easy-peasy really.

Download an app onto your phone called Music Download – Downloader (I am sure after trying this any number of other similar apps will work).

Open the Music Downloader app then click Browser and go to the Browser tab and click on one of the links to download a piece of music.  Download any song it doesn’t matter.

Once downloaded plug in your phone and navigate to the phone Documents > Music Player > Library > MusicDownloader2Free-offlinecaches > Data and there you should see your downloaded music file.  The library is now set up properly and drag your music over into the same folder.

Check your phone and all the files will be there.  Simples!  Now you can create playlists & all sorts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ifile Browser and then Documents on Iphone may show when you open folder and then open ifle and documents and drop there and run ifile on the iphone and the song can be played from there

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you explain in greater detail how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me with [Banshee](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=banshee) for music synchronisation.

Comment: banshee is gone in 22.04

Comment: check the date of the question and provide an up-to-date answer

Comment: sure, it was a good solution by then, but the info that it is gone is also valuable here by now. Is there a way to install banshee in newer Ubuntu releases?

Answer (score 0):

Got the app *Evermusic* from the app store. I have got an iphone4S with OS 9.3.

When I plug in my iphone to my desktop with Ubuntu 16.04 I will see a map *Evermusic* in *Documents on [name of my iPhone]* to which I can copy the desired music files from my desktop.
And will be able to play them on my phone offline.

Comment: Note it is with adds, to remove them you pay 18€ (and anyway: it doesn't work on my iOS 17)