# How can drag music to my apple iPhone 4s

Tags: installation, iphone, apple

I want to know how to drag and sync all my apple devices to linux because i already tried using Rythymbox,Banshee,Clementine,etc....

Comment: You can't. Call Apple and let them know how you feel. *Yeah, it sucks. I agree.*

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/158486/how-do-i-transfer-music-to-my-iphone and http://askubuntu.com/questions/83484/what-is-the-current-state-of-apple-device-iphone-ipod-etc-support

Answer (score 0):

There are other apps you can use. Dropbox has a music player that will play music from dropbox, and there's a dropbox app for iPhone. There are other apps that will play from other cloud storage services that work with the iPhone. But Apple just doesn't seem to want to work with Linux - probably some conflict between their business model of charging for air and sunlight when they can and the Open Source community's dislike of proprietary formats and DRM.