# "ERROR: File doesn't exist" when trying to transfer files to iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and want to transfer some videos to my iPhone 5 (iOS7) to it.

When I connect the phone it is mounted correctly and I can see all the DCIM, Photo... folders in nautilus. But where do I copy my .mp4 files?

I have searched the net but all is related to syncing music files (mp3).
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151584/how-to-copy-existing-movie-files-on-ipad-to-watch), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158486/how-do-i-transfer-music-to-my-iphone), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83484/what-is-the-current-state-of-apple-device-iphone-ipod-etc-support).

Also, when I try to copy something in Document Folder or inside any app (2nd mounted iPhone point) it gives me an error:

```
ERROR: File doesn't exist
```

So, is there any folder in 1st mounted point (like DCIM, Photo etc..) where I can simply copy my MP4 files and watch it in my iPhone?

(NOTE: I don't need sync function but will not harm if it can be achieved).

**EDIT:**

Now I see two more problems:

1. For some reason my Document Folder is not mounted any more (even after unmounting and restarting). Only the Picture, DCIM etc. folders are mounted.
2. I sometimes get this:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**
When I tried the troubleshoot method in 1st link of duplicate I get 
Error: Pairing with device xxxxx failed with unhandled error code -20.
(And my phone was not locked)

Also, I get on re-connecting:

[image]

Comment: This is not the same question !!! Please correct it. As I said in my question I cannot copy anything in Document Folder or inside any app, so how can this be duplicate?

Comment: How do you mount it?

Comment: @Braiam : I plug it in with my USB cable and it mounts automatically. In my Unity I have two mounted devices shown, one contains folders such as DCIM, Photo etc. & the other shows my Document folder with all the apps in it.

Comment: Can you add to the question the output of `mount` after it's mounted.

Comment: @Braiam: I see other problems too now, the document folder is not mounted & I also get an error. But my regular folder (with Pic folder) are mounted normally.

Comment: Roshan:  Did you try the steps under the "troubleshooting" section in the first answer on the duplicate question?

Answer (score -1):

The [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/151585/54256) should help here.

To summarise it:

1. Install a video player app on the device such as "Flexplayer".
2. Plug the device into your computer via USB
3. Navigate to "Documents on My iPhone" in your file browser.  If you do not see this under mounted devices, make sure the `libimobiledevice-utils` and `ifuse` packages are installed on Ubuntu.
4. Find the folder for the video player you installed, eg "Flexplayer".
5. Drag the video files into this folder.
6. You may need to close and re-open the video player app on the device before the new videos appear.

Note that iPhones and iPads do not act like regular drives on your computer where you can access all files as if it's a USB drive or MTP device - if you try this all you'll be able to do is see photos taken by the device camera.  Instead you need special drivers such as those used by iTunes.  However, Ubuntu now has built-in support at least for the ability to access document storage on iDevices, as described above, and that's what provides the "Documents on my iPhone" mount point.

Comment: Hi neon, I am unable to copy anything in my documents folder of iphone (as already stated in question). I can however copy or create folders in the 1st mounted point (with DCIM, Photo folder)

Comment: What happened when you followed the above steps though?  Including installing a video player such as Flexplayer on the device, then trying to locate the Flexplayer folder in the documents folder?  You can't just copy stuff straight into the root documents folder of the phone.

Comment: As I wrote in the question it gives me File dosen't exist error when I try to copy files in it, I have also edited the question...