# Unable to mount Iphone 5s

Tags: mount, iphone

How do I  mount Iphone 5S in my 14.04 ?

I have executed

```
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils ifuse
idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair
```

as mentioned in http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/02/fix-unhandled-lockdown-error-when.html but I'm not getting

```
ERROR: Pairing with device 3210ad9523e3c5a47934707dfdf2d8dfd8cce1fe failed with unhandled error code -20
```

Comment: same http://askubuntu.com/questions/458641/error-file-doesnt-exist-when-trying-to-transfer-files-to-iphone http://askubuntu.com/questions/662668/error-while-jailbreaking-iphone4-with-spirit-on-ubuntu Generic: http://askubuntu.com/questions/151584/how-to-copy-existing-movie-files-on-ipad-to-watch

Comment: Hmmm... in simple words, mounting Iphone in Linux is not supported directly ?

Comment: Sort of ... it seems like it has mixed results :-X For some it works for some it does not. Weird. Hopefully someone with more knowledge comes along ;-)

Comment: It comes preinstalled in a particular distribution and it works but I think it's not allowed to talk about other distros here...